# Original data from List changes inside a method even if duplicating the original List

Tags: android, pointers, reference, arraylist

Why do I get original data changed in the calling method, even if copying the original List using the following in the called method :

```
originalDatesSerie = datesSerie ;
```

instead of using :

```
originalDatesSerie.addAll(datesSerie) ;
```

The original List is kept as it in the calling method when using `addAll` in the called method, so result is as expected in that case.

Here is the piece of the ugly code which is Ok (but NOK if using a direct equal assignment) :

```
    private static HashMap<String, Object> autoScaling(List<Date[]> datesSerie, List<double[]> valuesSerie,
                HashMap<String, Long> xminMax) {

        // Copy original List (required to keep them unchanged)
        List<Date[]> originalDatesSerie = new ArrayList<Date[]> ();
        originalDatesSerie.addAll(datesSerie);//do NOT use "="
        List<double[]> originalValuesSerie = new ArrayList<double[]> ();
        originalValuesSerie.addAll(valuesSerie);//do NOT use "="

...

        // Concat new datas with original datas
        originalDatesSerie.addAll(Xaxis);
        originalValuesSerie.addAll(Yaxis);
}
```

Comment: @blackbelt: The question is : why is the original list not considered as a local data in the called method despite it's locally duplicated. If it's duplicated as a reference (using equal), it gets modified, which is NOK. When it's copied using addALL, then the orginal List keeps unchanged, which is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example (`originalDatesSerie = datesSerie ;`) you are assigning a reference to `dateSerie` to `originalDatesSerie`, meaning that both are referencing the same `ArrayList`.  When you make a change to an object through one reference or add/delete objects, it is reflected in both.

In the second example `originalDatesSerie.addAll(datesSerie) ;`, `originalDatesSerie` references each of the objects in `dateSerie`, but the references are a separate set of references (`ListArray`).  When you add objects to `originalDatesSerie`, you are adding them to a separate collection.

Comment: Thx. What I don't understand is why referencing the same List from different methods leads to a kind of reference priority to the called method local data privacy. In my understanding that should keep the List private to this method.

Comment: `oringalDatesSerie` is "private" to the method and you will not be able to reference it outside the method in which it is declared.  It is, however, a pointer to a collection.  By using assignment, it is told to point to the same thing that `datesSerie` is pointing to.  While java always passes arguments by value, if you pass an object, it is the object reference you are passing, and modifications you make to the object will be reflected back to the caller.  See http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I get original data changed in the calling method, even if copying the original List using the following in the called method :

It does not matter what sort of copying you use - addAll() or '='. Your item elements are Dates which are mutable objects. Mutable objects whose references exist on two different lists can be mutated from either list. Pass immutable objects between the functions to isolate them.

Comment: Thx. It makes a difference as the original list is not modified if copying it without reference.